# Why isn't this returning null?

Tags: javascript

Let's run this javascript code:

```
var value = parseInt("");
console.log(value != Number.NaN? value : null);
```

Why does this code outputs `Nan` in the console instead of `null`?

How can I change my code to actually get a `null` object ?

I try to wrap my code in a function like this:

```
function parseIntOrDefault(value, def){
    var candidate = parseInt(value);
    if(candidate != Number.NaN) return candidate; else return def;    
}

console.log(parseIntOrDefault('', null));
```

But this behaves the same.

Here is a jsFiddle that illustrate my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/stevebeauge/BRP94/

Comment: Because it is not `null`.  It is, instead, `Not a Number`

Comment: Have you tried using [isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FisNaN)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use

```
isNaN(value);
```

to check for `NaN`

Because:

```
console.log(NaN === NaN); // false!
```

**`NaN` is not equal to itself**.

This may seem weird but it makes sense if you think about the nature of `NaN`.

Let's say you have this code:

```
var a, b, c;
// a = 0;oops a is still undefined so we'll get NaN if we do an operation with it
b = 5;
c = 6
if (a + b === a + c) {
    console.log("math error?");
}
```

You don't want to come to the seeming conclusion that 5 === 6.

Comment: `NaN!==NaN`?  That's just throwing basic logic out the window :D

Comment: @DavidStarkey A dog is not a number, and a banana is also not a number, but that doesn't mean `dog === banana`.

Comment: Not a Number IS Not a Number.  Saying Not a Number is not Not a Number is like saying Not a Number is a Number... Crazy ways to read code.  It's like if you said Logic is based on the premise `A=A` but in this case `A!=A`, so all logic is now rendered unreliable. :)

Comment: @Juhana But what confuses me is that `NaN` is just a reference to a function, right? So why wouldn't the references be equal? Maybe I'm missing something obvious. I need to Google this... **EDIT:** Nevermind, I'm thinking about `isNaN`, not `NaN`

Comment: Thanks Frits van Campen, this solved my issue. I've learned a new thing today. I'll mark your answer as soon as I'm allowed to do.

Comment: Math (and logic) has support for constructions like `NaN`. When you say 5 === 5 = true you're saying that 5 shares the same identity, `NaN` does not share an identity.

Comment: @Juhana Yeah nevermind, I realized that after I commented and edited my comment, sorry :)

Comment: @DavidStarkey This subject confuses me too; maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan

Comment: @DavidStarkey @Juhana It'd make more sense if if `NaN === NaN` evaluated to something representing "unknown", instead of actually evaluating to `false`.  In that case, you could use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic  Saying `+"dog" === +"banana"` might be a bit crazy, but certainly no more so than saying `+"dog" !== +"dog"`

Comment: @TimGoodman `something representing "unknown"`...like `undefined`? Haha

Comment: @Ian Yeah, but I didn't want to offer an opinion on whether it should be `undefined` or `null` or whatever, so I was intentionally vague.  In JavaScript `undefined` is already used as the value of a variable that has never had a value assigned to it.  If you have `var x; x = (NaN == NaN);` it isn't totally obvious to me that `x` should be in the same state after the second line as it is after the first line.

Comment: Really, where JavaScript uses `undefined` I would prefer it used "unassigned".  Instead we get weirdness where accessing `x` gives an `x is not defined` error, unless you first say `var x;`, after which it is now defined... as `undefined`. ;)

Comment: @TimGoodman Oh no, I completely understand and agree...I was just being a pain :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isNaN(candidate))return null; else return candidate;
```

Comment: Thanks @user2532546, but a single lone of code, without explanation won't be very useful.

Comment: w3schools.com is not a legitimate reference. Search for "w3fools"