# Haskell: comparing NaN values

Tags: haskell, nan

I wrote [**`quickcheck`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) tests for a Haskell program that optimizes and evaluates a function.

The problem is [**`quickcheck`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) generates expressions resulting in `NaN` like:

```
> acos(2)
NaN
```

Haskell evaluates the following statement as false:

```
> acos(2)==acos(2)
False
```

So my [**`quickcheck`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.1/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) tests fail with this comparison.
Is there any way to compare `NaN` values?

Comment: NaN compares not equal to itself, by design. If you want to work with NaNs, you have to use `isNaN` or similar.

Comment: I noticed, however thats not what i want, because my tests fail that way. And there is no such thing as a NaN constant, so I cant check if a value is NaN.

Comment: isNan did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, as is defined by [IEEE 754](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/References.xhtml) comparing 2 `NaN`s always return false. To chceck if your value is `NaN` in Haskell you can use [`isNaN`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:isNaN) method or write it by yourself

```
isNaN' :: a -> Bool
isNaN' a = a /= a
```

Comment: IMO NaN should compare equal to NaN. I know that two NaN's are not necessarily the same value, but returning false breaks all kinds of laws, as well as things like putting floats in a Set or a Map. Also things like `compare nan nan = GT` but `nan > nan = False`. Particularly since `inf == inf` returns True. When that kind of thing is just as undecidable as comparing NaN values. (`nan = 0.0/0` and `inf = 1.0/0` in my examples)

Comment: There is rationale of that on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values/1573715#1573715) by one of the IEEE committee. I won't argue with you but read what he has written. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23666623/1017941) is good rationale for that design choice.