# Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive for Haskell function without `otherwise` clause

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Consider a function `disjoint :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool` which checks if there exists a common element between two sorted lists (and if it does, it returns `False` since they *wouldn't* be disjointed).

```hs
disjoint :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
disjoint [] _ = True
disjoint _ [] = True
disjoint (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x == y = False
  | x < y = disjoint xs (y:ys)
  | x > y = disjoint (x:xs) ys
```

In my IDE `vscode`, it yields the following warning:

```
Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
In an equation for ‘disjoint’: Patterns not matched: (_:_) (_:_)compile(-Wincomplete-patterns)
```

Writing it in a different yet similar way, by using the `otherwise` clause, will yield no errors:

```hs
disjoint :: (Eq a, Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
disjoint [] _ = True
disjoint _ [] = True
disjoint (x:xs) (y:ys)
  | x < y = disjoint xs (y:ys)
  | x > y = disjoint (x:xs) ys
  | otherwise = False
```

What "pattern" does the first code block "miss"? In other words, at what parameters will the first block of code have problems with?

Comment: It does not know that if `x < y` does not hold, and `x > y` does not hold, that `x == y` will always hold.

Comment: So it is possible for two values of type `Eq a, Ord a` where none of the three relations hold? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @janreggie You can define a custom (bogus) instance for a user-defined type where all the comparisons are always false. Also, NaN in floating point arithmetic have this nasty behavior.

Comment: I'm testing it right now and you're right. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that, when checking exhaustiveness, GHC ignores a guarded equation like `foo Pattern | condition1 = .... | condition2 = ...` unless the very last guard is `otherwise` or `True`. In all the other cases, GHC is conservative and assumes there are cases that fall through all the guards (even if the guards are indeed exhaustive like `f x | ()==() = "hi"`). A semi-rationale is: if you know they are exhaustive, you should "optimize" your code anyway, replacing the last guard with `otherwise` which is faster than any actual test.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Eq` is a superclass of `Ord` so you can omit it from the constraint.

You can use `compare` to turn it into `data Ordering = LT | EQ | GT` which only has three cases, allowing the compiler to infer exhaustiveness.

```
disjoint :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
disjoint [] _ = True
disjoint _ [] = True
disjoint (x:xs) (y:ys) =
  case x `compare` y of
    EQ -> False
    LT -> disjoint xs (y:ys)
    GT -> disjoint (x:xs) ys
```

Answer (score 3):

From @chi's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68286159/pattern-matches-are-non-exhaustive-for-haskell-function-without-otherwise-cl?noredirect=1#comment120686265_68286159):

Consider the following data type:

```hs
data TT = Bogus 
instance Eq TT where
  Bogus == Bogus = False
instance Ord TT where
  Bogus <= Bogus = False
  Bogus < Bogus = False
  Bogus >= Bogus = False
  Bogus > Bogus = False
```

Any comparisons between a `Bogus` and a `Bogus` returns `False`. Because of that,

```
> disjoint [Bogus, Bogus] [Bogus, Bogus]
*** Exception: Ch04Book.hs:(25,1)-(30,18): Non-exhaustive patterns in function disjoint
```

The same Exception is raised when running `disjoint [acos 2] [acos 2]` since [comparisons between `NaN`s always returns `False`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19810082/14020202).

Sidenote/implication: A type of typeclass `Ord` does not necessarily follow the [Law of excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle). See `Bogus` where both `Bogus < Bogus = False` and `Bogus >= Bogus = False`, and Haskell would not complain.

Comment: I wouldn't really call it bogus; `Ord` isn't required to implement a total order, so it's perfectly legal for distinct objects to be noncomparable.

Comment: @chepner What about `compare`, though? If it's not a total order, we have to make that crash (or fail to terminate). If `Ord` is not supposed to model a total order, it should not have a `compare` method, IMO. For the record, `compare (acos 2) (acos 2)` returns `GT` here.

Comment: The exhaustiveness checker does not know about the laws of *any* typeclasses. Even if `Ord` had some law which says that `==`, `<`, and `>` are exhaustive (disjoint), the compiler would give the same exact warning for the code in the OP. While all the statements in this answer are essentially true, they do not answer the question.