# Is NaN falsy? Why NaN === false returns false

Tags: javascript

1. Why `NaN === false` => false, isn't NaN falsy?
2. Why `NaN === NaN` => false, but `!!NaN === !!NaN` => true

I've been racking my brain trying to figure this out.

Comment: Because `typeof NaN !== typeof false`. Being falsy doesn't mean it's `=== false`, but `== false`

Comment: `typeof NaN === 'number'`

Comment: Do you understand the *strict* equality operator?

Comment: Because `===` isn't a "falsy" test.

Comment: May want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan

Comment: Btw, this will make you totally angry: `NaN === NaN // false`

Comment: And `NaN ==== NaN` will make you even angrier (syntax errors always do!)

Comment: @zerkms: I'd say falsy means `!!value === false`. For example, `" " == false` is `true`, even though we know that non-empty strings are truthy (`!!" "` is `true`).

Comment: Boolean(NaN) === false is probably how I would have tested for its falsy-ness

Comment: just a js dev having a field day

Comment: `NaN == false` is false. `NaN == true` is also false.

Comment: Adding:  NaN === NaN is false just like null = null in SQL is false.  However NaN !== NaN is true, whereas in SQL null != null is still false.  So a little inconsistency there - SQL really enforces that Null cannot be compared with anything, including itself, while NaN is comparable in Javascript.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

1. *Falsy* and being strictly equal to `false` are very different things, that's why one has a `y` instead of an `e`. ;)
2. `NaN` is spec'd to never be equal to anything. The second part of your question is comparing `false === false`, which is funnily enough, `true` :)

If you really want to know if something is `NaN`, you can use `Object.is()`. Running `Object.is(NaN, NaN)` returns `true`.

Comment: woow! Did not know this (NaN === NaN) === false

Comment: And (NaN !== NaN) returns true. NaN is the only JavaScript value unequal to itself.

Comment: NaN isn't a value then, for any purpose really.

Comment: @3Dom It's only purpose is to show that there was a computation error. But yes, it is weird. And in light of how `NaN` behaves it is also kind of weird that this *is true*: `Infinity === Infinity`.

Comment: "Falsy and being strictly equal to false are very different things" is really an important concept

Answer (score 20):

> 1.Why NaN === false => false, isn't NaN falsy?

The term "falsy" isn't defined in ECMA-262, it's jargon for where type conversion coerces a value to false. e.g.

```
var x = NaN;

if (!x) {
  console.log('x is "falsy"');
}
```

The strict equality operator uses the [Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) which checks that the arguments are of the same Type, and `NaN` is Type number, while `false` is Type boolean, so they evaluated as not equal based on Type, there is no comparison of value.

> 2.Why NaN === NaN => false, but !!NaN === !!NaN => true

Because the strict equality comparison algorithm states that `NaN !== NaN`, hence the [*isNaN*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4) method.

Using ! coerces the argument to boolean using the abstract [*ToBoolean*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2) method, where `!NaN`
converts to *true* and `!!NaN` converts to *false*, so:

```
!!NaN === !!NaN  -->  false === false  -->  true
```

Note that the abstract equality operator `==` will coerce the arguments to be of the same Type according to the rules for the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3). In this case, *NaN* is Type number, so *false* is converted to a number using *toNumber* which returns `0`. And `0` is not equal to *NaN* so:

```
NaN == false  -->  NaN == 0  -->  false
```

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 7):

This condition:

```
NaN === false
```

Is always `false` because numbers are not booleans. To test if a value is falsy you can use a ternary expression:

```
NaN ? "truthy" : "falsy" // falsy
```

> Why NaN === NaN => false

This is explained in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN); pragmatically speaking, though, two values of which you only know they're not numbers can't logically be the same thing.

> ... but why is !!NaN === !!NaN => true

This is because casting `NaN` into a boolean will make it `false` and booleans can be compared as per normal.

Comment: its pretty crazy how `NaN == false returns false` but `NaN ? 'truthy' : 'falsey' returns 'falsey'`

Comment: @maxwell—not really. 1. Per [*ECMA-262*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-numeric-types-number-equal) given `x == y` if either *x* or *y* are *NaN* the result is *false* (*NaN* is not `==` or `===` to any value, even *NaN*). 2. The [*conditional operator* `? :`](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-conditional-operator) first coerces the conditional expression (i.e. *NaN*) to boolean using [*ToBoolean*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-toboolean), and `ToBoolean(NaN)` returns *false* so the result of evaluating the right hand expression (i.e. the "falsey" one) is returned. :-)

Answer (score 0):

`===` compares both type and value.

Even though `NaN` is falsey, `===` wouldn't be the way to compare it. Something is "falsey" if it evaluates to false in a boolean expression. That isn't the same as being equal to (or equivalent to) false.

For example, `null == false` returns false, even though `null` is falsey. This is not completely intuitive, but that's just how JavaScript handles false/falsey values.

`0` and the blank string ("") are special cases where value equality comparisons against `false` evaluate to `true` (i.e. `0 == false` and `"" == false`). However, `0===false` and `""===false` still returns false.

`NaN` is special in that it doesn't have a real value, so comparing it to itself doesn't return true. Essentially, `NaN` is equal to nothing, not even `NaN`.

The only way to reliably compare something to NaN is using `isNaN( value )`.

---

To your second point, `!value` is a boolean expression. `value` first undergoes type coercion to a boolean (and remember, `NaN` is falsey) and then the boolean NOT `!` makes it true. As it happens, it's double negated, so `!!NaN` is the same as boolean `false`. Of course `false === false`, so the expression evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why NaN === false => false, isn't NaN falsy?

`NaN` as you are using, is a [global property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.1) initialized with [value of `Not-A-Number`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.23). It's not boolean. [It's NaN data type as defined by IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

It's the "same thing" you compare `null === false` (or even `null == false`).

In this case, **there is no difference using sctric equal or not:** `NaN == false`, also will return false!

> 1. Why NaN === NaN => false, but !!NaN === !!NaN => true

**2.1.** `NaN ==== NaN`, is false by definition.

**2.2.** But in `!!NaN === !!NaN`, you aren't comparing NaNs anymore, when you do **!**[value], you "evaluate" it (or cast to a boolean).

I'm gonna now explain with `null`, because it's more used, so you can apply it to `NaN`:

Casting NaN, it's the same thing that casting `null`.

```
null == false? true : false     // false! because it's not a bool false.<br>
!null? true: false              // true! because !null -> true -> if(true)...
```

**More Refs:**

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.1
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: *NaN* is initialised with the [*IEEE 754 “Not-a-Number” value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.23), which allows for different types of NaN.

Comment: ...so? just as I said: `global property initialized with value of Not-A-Number`

Comment: [to ECMAScript code, all NaN values are indistinguishable from each other.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)

Comment: Yes, it's just that your answer could be read as the value being the string "Not-a-Number" rather than a value that represents not being a number. Nit–picking maybe… :-/

Comment: ah! didn't see that misspelling.. thanks! I've improved the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This comparison also returns `false`:

```js
const x = NaN
const y = x

console.log(x === y) // false
```

Answer (score -3):

NaN and false are both the subset of Falsy.

- NaN == false  -> they're both falsy   -> thus 'TRUE'
- NaN === false -> they're **NOT** the same type -> thus 'FALSE'

Comment: NaN == false is false.