# NaN in Javascript

Tags: javascript, nan

In Javascript, I found this:

```
if (!NaN)
     console.log('do sth');
```

This code works, but if I write:

```
if (NaN)
     console.log('do sth');
```

This one is not work. I don't really understand the logic behind this.

Comment: NaN is falsy.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600248/is-nan-falsy-why-nan-false-returns-false.  If you would like to check if something is NaN, there's a special function called isNaN  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Comment: *"I don't really understand the logic behind this"* - Even without knowing what NaN is that code makes sense, because if `!something` is true then logically `something` is false. So (again, even without knowing what NaN is) you would expect one of those console.log() statements to be executed but not the other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NaN` is a special number in JavaScript which is used to symbolize an illegal number a.k.a. Not-A-Number, such as when try to multiply a number with a string, etc.

Now, in JS, there is the concept of [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). As you can see `NaN` is classified as a falsy value.

This is why when you execute the following:

```
if(NaN) {
  console.log("something");
}
```

..it doesn't work, because `NaN` is evaluated to false. And therefore, similarly the `if(!NaN)` conditional evaluates to true.

Comment: What do you mean by "NaN is a special number"? NaN means "not a number" so it's definitely not a number, especially not a "special number".

Comment: If you check the value of `typeof NaN` you will get `"number"`. Similarly if you check the output of `NaN.constructor.name` you will get `"Number"`. Hence, why I said it's a special number.

Comment: @RocoCTZ - Try `typeof NaN`.  You'll see it's a "number".

Comment: Thanks Blaze. Now I understand the falsy values part. Never heard about it before.