# .filter() in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript

```
  .filter(
    (item) => {
      console.log(this.timeFilter);  // line 1 
      if(this.timeFilter == NaN ) { return true; }   // line 2
      console.log("why log this?"); // line 3
      return item.endTime < this.timeFilter;
    }
  )
```

my code is above, I have a question that even if the this.timeFilter == NaN, it does not go the line 2, but go line 3 actually, not so sure what happened

```
NaN // line 1 output
why log this?  // line 3 output happen
```

Comment: Hint: `NaN == NaN` is `false` (and there's probably a well-written duplicate for you somewhere...)

Comment: See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600248/is-nan-falsy-why-nan-false-returns-false

Comment: thanks everyone!!! I fixed it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NaN == NaN` returns `false` in javascript. This is to prevent operations like

```
'somename' / 5 == 'someothername' / 5; // should not return true (both are NaN)
```

Use `isNaN`:

`if(this.timeFilter == NaN)` should be actually `if(!isNaN(this.timeFilter))`

Answer (score 2):

This is an incorrect comparison. You need to use function [isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). Something  like next:

```
.filter(
    (item) => {
      console.log(this.timeFilter);  // line 1 
      if(isNaN(this.timeFilter)) { return true; }   // line 2
      console.log("why log this?"); // line 3
      return item.endTime < this.timeFilter;
    }
  )
```

Comment: sorry for only one solution for each problem