# the || and NaN operator. How do they really work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nan, enumerable

Let's say I have an array of words, and I would like to use an object to get the count of it.  I tried this:

```
const results = {};

const words = ["word", "hello", "code", "five", "hello", "word", "new", "code"];

words.forEach( word => {
  results[word] = results[word] + 1 || 1;  
});
```

`results` in this case returns:

```
{ word: 2, hello: 2, code: 2, five: 1, new: 1 }
```

`NaN === false` is `false` and `results[word] + 1 => NaN`.  I don't quite understand why results wouldn't be:

```
{ word: NaN, hello: NaN, code: NaN, five: NaN, new: NaN }
```

Someone care to explain? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is NaN falsy? Why NaN === false returns false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600248/is-nan-falsy-why-nan-false-returns-false)

Comment: @JaromandaX it is, because `undefined + 1` is `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

`results[word]` when `results` doesn't contain `word` is `undefined`. Though `NaN === false` is `false`, it's still a falsy value (`!!NaN` is `false`).

Therefore, `results[word] + 1 || 1` = `undefined + 1 || 1` = `NaN || 1` = `1`.

Answer (score -1):

`undefined`+`1` = `NaN`

```
results[word] = results[word] + 1 || 1;
```

You're initializing the value at one where the || (or) operation sets the default to 1 instead of 0. The way I solved this was wrapping the condition like so:

```
results[word] = (results[word] || 0)+1;
```