# console.log(parseInt(params.page) === NaN); is false in my terminal even when parseInt(params.page) comes up as NaN in my terminal

Tags: javascript, if-statement, types, integer, parseint

I have this code sample:

```
if (!params || params?.page == null) {
        console.log('condition 1');
        inputParam = 1;
    } else if (parseInt(params.page) == NaN) {
        console.log('condition 2');
        inputParam = 1;
    } else if (parseInt(params.page) < 0 || parseInt(params.page) > 42) {
        console.log('condition 3');
        inputParam = 1;
    } else {
        console.log('condition else');
        inputParam = params.page;
    }
    console.log(params.page);
    console.log(parseInt(params.page));
    console.log(inputParam);
    console.log(parseInt(params.page) === NaN);
    const processedParam = parseInt(inputParam);
    console.log(processedParam);
```

I've been running this in a node app that I have. I get this in my console.

```
condition else
oh
NaN
oh
false
NaN
```

Why is `else if (parseInt(params.page) == NaN) {` not catching, and why is `console.log(parseInt(params.page) === NaN);` reading `false` when it's clearly supposed to be `true`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is NaN falsy? Why NaN === false returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600248/is-nan-falsy-why-nan-false-returns-false). It is already described how NaN behaves when compared. So to compare NaN there are other possible options you can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I changed my code to this:

```
if (!params || params?.page == null) {
        console.log('condition 1');
        inputParam = 1;
    } else if (isNaN(params.page)) {
        console.log('condition 2');
        inputParam = 1;
    } else if (parseInt(params.page) < 0 || parseInt(params.page) > 42) {
        console.log('condition 3');
        inputParam = 1;
    } else {
        console.log('condition else');
        inputParam = params.page;
    }
    const processedParam = parseInt(inputParam);
```

and my terminal printed `condition 2` when `params.page` was set to "oh"