# _.indexOf() `item !== item` - what is its purpose?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, indexof

Looking into `Underscore.js` code and more specifically into `_.indexOf()` function (find code with comments [**here**](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html))

```
_.indexOf = function(array, item, isSorted) {
    var i = 0, length = array && array.length;
    if (typeof isSorted == 'number') {
      i = isSorted < 0 ? Math.max(0, length + isSorted) : isSorted;
    } else if (isSorted && length) {
      i = _.sortedIndex(array, item);
      return array[i] === item ? i : -1;
    }
    if (item !== item) {
      return _.findIndex(slice.call(array, i), _.isNaN);
    }
    for (; i < length; i++) if (array[i] === item) return i;
    return -1;
};
```

I noticed the `if(item !== item){...}` statement, but I don't get its purpose. `items` is a parameter and it's not changed inside the function. When would a variable differ from itself?

Am I missing something?

Comment: this is for the the future me: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) [NaNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) are not equal to themselves.** The `if` statement is checking whether `item` is a NaN. If it is, the function needs to use special logic since the search loop testing for `array[i] === item` won't work.

For further discussion, see [Why is NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan) and [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

Answer (score 2):

The number constant `NaN` is never `===` to another value, including itself. Thus that's a way to test for `NaN` without a function call. Absolutely any other value of `item` would test equal to itself:

- `undefined` is `===` to `undefined`
- `null` is `===` to `null`
- a number is equal to itself, as is a string or a boolean
- a reference to an object is `===` to itself (and *only* to itself!)