# Google script parseInt and NaN - how it really works?

Tags: google-apps-script, nan, parseint

I'm going to check if certain variable is a string or number.
I use `parseInt()` function which returns `NaN` (Not a Number) if value is a string.
But, when I try to check it in if statement it looks like `"NaN"` output can't be treated as a valid condition to check. Any guess why?

```
function tsCalculate() {
  var string = "Monday";
  var number = 1;
  Logger.log(string);
  Logger.log(number);
  Logger.log("String after parseInt: " + parseInt(string, 10));
  Logger.log("Number after parseInt: " + parseInt(number, 10));
  if ("NaN" == parseInt(string, 10))
  {
    Logger.log("doesn't work");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`NaN` is:

- not a string (it is [a value in its own right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN))
- [not equal to other things which are also `NaN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan)

Use [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) to determine if a value is equal to `NaN`.

```
if (isNaN(parseInt(string, 10))) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is just a follow up as I am learning things here.  Is NaN a reserved object type?   Would the following also be a valid statement:

```
if (NaN === parseInt(String,10)) {...}
```