# In which cases val !== val? (compare a variable with itself)

Tags: javascript, types, nan

I'm just creating a function that will `JSON.stringify` an input but also detecting `NaN` on number inputs, but don't want to use `typeof` because of reasons stated below. The input could be either a `number`, `boolean` or `string`. Nothing more.

I've reached the situation where `NaN !== NaN`, so:

```
if (input !== input || input === Infinity || input === -Infinity) {
    output = input.toString();
} else {
    output = JSON.stringify(input);
}
```

I'm doing it this way because `JSON.stringify()` returns `"null"` when the value is `NaN` or `Infinity`.

I know that with `typeof` and `toString()` this is pretty easy to achieve, but some performance tests shows that `typeof` under IE11 is really slow (4-5 times slower than `JSON.stringify()` under our situation), and we need to focus on IE11 here.

I would like to know if there are more cases where `val !== val`.

Here you have a performance test: https://jsperf.com/typeof-vs-nan-nan2
Not used the SO one because seems that they run the codes server side, as there IE performance is as good as elsewhere. Impossibru thing.

Local test is:

```
var mockdata = [];

function notToJson(val) {
    return val !== val || val === Infinity || val === -Infinity;
}

for (var i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);
    if (Math.random()>0.5) {
        n = n.toString();
    } else if (Math.random()>0.5) {
        if (Math.random()>0.5) {
            n = NaN;
        } else {
            if (Math.random()>0.5) {
                n = Infinity;
            } else {
                n = -Infinity;
            }
        }
    }
    mockdata.push(n);
}

console.time("typeof");
for (i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    var res = typeof mockdata[i] === "string";
}
console.timeEnd("typeof");

console.time("notToJson");
for (i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    res = notToJson(mockdata[i]);
}
console.timeEnd("notToJson");

console.time("toString");
for (i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    res = mockdata[i].toString();
}
console.timeEnd("toString");

console.time("JSON.stringify");
for (i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    res = JSON.stringify(mockdata[i]);
}
console.timeEnd("JSON.stringify");

console.time("Full typeof");
for (i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    res = typeof mockdata[i]==="string"?JSON.stringify(mockdata[i]):mockdata[i].toString();
}
console.timeEnd("Full typeof");

console.time("Full notToJson");
for (i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
    res = notToJson(mockdata[i])?mockdata[i].toString():JSON.stringify(mockdata[i]);
}
console.timeEnd("Full notToJson");
```

Chrome output is:

[image]

But IE11 output is:

[image]

I've noticed that the less strings `mockdata` has, the performance of `typeof` is noticeably increased (Talking about IE11).

Comment: *but don't want to use typeof because of reasons*, and the reasons are?

Comment: The reasons are that it is slow in IE11, as you can read in the question.

Comment: `{} !== {}` That's the only other thing I can think of in JS where `val !== val`

Comment: @George—but that is to different objects.

Comment: @George Nice. We are safe here then.

Comment: @RobG that's why they don't equal each other...

Comment: Please post a [mcve] using the `<>` snippet editor

Comment: @George—but they are two different values. What the OP is looking for is when a value isn't equal to itself, and `var a = {}; a === a` is true, but `var b = NaN; b === b` is false.

Comment: @mplungjan Oh yeah. Still not used to that editor altough has beet here a while ago... going to edit.

Comment: @RobG Yes, you're correct. My bad.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan ?

Comment: Use [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)? Also is typeof really so slow it matters at all when a JSON.stringify is used? PS: there are more abstruse cases where, in some way, `val !== val`. One construction i could think of is when any kind of code is being executed in between the lookups, e.g. for getters, implicit valueOf calls and so on.

Comment: `input !== input || input === Infinity || input === -Infinity` can be easily replaced with `isNaN(input) || !isFinite(input)`

Comment: @Andrey No, because I want to stringify strings (altough they contain numbers). That case will accept strings as numbers.

Comment: @mplungjan This is a completely different question...

Comment: @ASDFGerte IE11 don't has `Number.isNaN`. Not a surprise btw...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm going to answer this myself as I don't like to have unanswered questions.*

Note how the question talks about `val`. What I mean is to assign a value to a variable, and later compare the variable *with itself*. **Not to create two different variables** and compare them.

From my own tests, `val !== val` only when `val = NaN`, so:

```js
var val = NaN;
console.log("val !== val:", val !== val);
```

The reason is right here: [Why is NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan)

Answer (score 2):

Here are some cases where `val !== val` returns true:

```
console.log({} !== {}); // true
console.log(new Date() !== new Date()); // true
console.log(new String("") !== new String("")); // true
```

That only applies when the objects are different:

```
var a = b = {}; // now they are equal
console.log(a !== b); // false
```

It also happens with [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) (ES6 feature):

```
console.log(Symbol() !== Symbol()); // true
```

Comment: All these are different objects, as already stated in the comments. Note the `val` in `val !== val`. I want to assign something to a variable and check that variable.