# Is it expected that identity returns something different from its argument?

Tags: clojure, nan, equality

Here is an example where calling [`identity`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/identity) changes the returned value, which seems to me to indicate that the docstring "Returns its argument." isn't entirely true:

```
(let [x Double/NaN] (identical? x x)) ;=> false
(let [x (identity Double/NaN)] (identical? x x)) ;=> true
```

Is this expected? Or is it a bug with the `identity` function somehow?

Comment: This is probably due to boxing - `Double/NaN` returns a primitive `double` which is boxed twice in the first example but only once in the second.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to have found an edge case involving `identity`, `identical?`, and primitive vs object equality. Note that in Java, [java.lang.Double/NaN is a primitive:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NaN)

```
public static final double NaN
```

But identical compares Java Objects:

```
; clojure.core
(defn identical?
  "Tests if 2 arguments are the same object"
  {:inline (fn [x y] `(. clojure.lang.Util identical ~x ~y))
   :inline-arities #{2}
   :added "1.0"}
  ([x y] (clojure.lang.Util/identical x y)))

// clojure/lang/Util.java
static public boolean identical(Object k1, Object k2){
    return k1 == k2;
}
```

Try this trick to force the NaN into a Double object instead of an unboxed primitive:

```
tupelo.core=> (let [x (Double. Double/NaN)] 
  (spyxx x) 
  (identical? x x))

x => java.lang.Double->NaN
true
```

I suspect that autoboxing of the primitive NaN which may/may not occur with different use-cases is the cause of the differences you are seeing.

Comment: The trick at the end is just the same thing as what this question is asking: you box NaN up in a Double, just as identity does in the question. It's not really a different thing. I think the only thing this answer is missing is an explanation of why both `identity` and `identical?` entail autoboxing.

Answer (score 3):

To add a little color to Alan's answer on boxing:

You may want to look into the `==` function, which is implemented this way:

```
public boolean equiv(Number x, Number y){
    return x.doubleValue() == y.doubleValue();
}
```

This performs a primitive comparison of two actual `double`s. Your example, with `==`:

```
(let [x (identity Double/NaN)] (== x x))
=> false
(let [x (identity Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY)] (== x x))
=> true
```

What's going on?  Why is `NaN == NaN` false?  Well, a primitive comparison using `==` **should actually return false for `NaN`**. It's strangely specified this way in [IEEE 754](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan) and Java behaves this way. It's the only "number" which, when compared to itself, does not equal itself.

As an aside, to see how object equality can be a strange thing in Java, see this:

```
(identical? 127 127)
=> true
(identical? 128 128)
=> false
```

This is because java caches the first 2^8 unsigned ints, so the `127`s being compared are the same object in the first example, but the `128`s in the second example are different objects. So, there are some gotchas to be aware of with checking for equality!

But the main takeaway here is: `identity` is working as it should! Just be careful when comparing things, as the notion of "equality" is not so straightforward!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about the fact that the returned values are different from each other, and not about what specifically those returned values are.

Answer (score 0):

Does `identity` *"return its argument"*?

It depends what you mean by the *argument*.

- If it is *the evaluated expression in the function call form*, then *not always*.
- If it is *what the body of the function sees on the stack upon entry*, then *yes, it does*.

The anomaly arises because of the way that Clojure calls functions.

- Clojure functions are objects that comply with [the `IFn`
  interface](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java).
- A Clojure function call translates into one of the many `invoke`
  methods - overloaded for arity - of the function object.
- All of the `invoke` methods have `Object` parameters.

The upshot of all this is that every Clojure function call translates its every argument into some kind of `Object` - an identity operation except on primitives, which are wrapped in the corresponding Java class: `long` into `Long`, and so on.

So even the `identity` function, essentially `(defn identity [x] x)`, does not return a primitive argument. It can't, because it never sees it.

---

For example, let's consider the expression

```
(inc 3)
```

The number `3` is surely a `long`. What type is `(inc 3)`? Let's ask Clojure:

```
(type (inc 3))
=> java.lang.Long
```

... a *boxed* `Long` object.

Hang on, are we sure that `3` is a primitive `long`?:

```
(type 3)
=> java.lang.Long
```

Aaaaaaagh! It's boxed too!

**Not necessarily**! You can't tell, because by the time the body of `type` sees `3`, it *is* boxed, whether or not it was so to the reader/compiler. The [Clojure documentation](https://clojure.org/reference/reader#_literals) is silent on the point. It just says that numeric literals are *generally represented as per Java*.

So - in general - **it's the evaluation mechanism, not a particular function (such as `identity`) that's responsible for boxing primitive arguments**. This is auto-boxing.

What your example shows is that primitives are held as such, un-boxed, at least in `let` forms:

```
(let [x 1.0] (identical? x x)) ;=> false
(let [x (identity 1.0)] (identical? x x)) ;=> true
```

The fact that `identical?` is able to distinguish between the two boxings of `1.0` shows that it is held as a primitive `double`. (I've used an ordinary `double`, just to show that the behaviour is nothing to do with the special value `Double/NaN`).

Now let's try putting the number in a var:

```
(def x 1.0)

(identical? x x) ;=> true
(let [x (identity x)] (identical? x x)) ;=> true
```

It's boxed.

While we're here, auto-boxing is idempotent:

```
(identical? x (identity x)) ;=> true
```

---

The above adds little to what [Alan Thompson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789133/1562315) and [Josh's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44790513/1562315) answers and Alan Malloy's  and Lee's comments comprise. I just felt they had hooked and played the fish, without actually landing it.