# Why adding multiple 'nan' in python dictionary giving multiple entries?

Tags: python, dictionary

Example problem:

```
import numpy as np
dc = dict()
dc[np.float('nan')] = 100
dc[np.float('nan')] = 200
```

It is creating multiple entries for `nan` like

`dc.keys()` will produce `{nan: 100, nan: 200}` but it should create `{nan: 200}`.

Comment: This is a consequence of the fact that ```np.nan == np.nan``` is False. Probably best to avoid using this as a key.

Comment: @user55449 Don't you mean that `np.nan != np.nan`?

Comment: @user55449 ITYM `np.nan != np.nan`

Comment: Yep, thanks... Slight difference there.

Comment: I'm actually surprised. I remember Raymond Hetinger talking about it in PyCon and he gave me impression that this behavior is not a thing (https://youtu.be/npw4s1QTmPg)

Comment: I dont even can apply `dc.has_key(np.float('nan'))` it is giving False

Comment: @dojo because this, too, is based on the equality operator. Do the answers below make sense to you?

Comment: yes, but my problem is, I am getting multiple nan from data provider and I need to create a dictionary for every value coming. So, I am trying to check at least if the value is already exist then dont put a entry. Now I am doing this by cheking `np.isnan(np.float('nan'))`. It works for me.. Thank you.

Comment: AMAZINGly, this doesn't reproduce when using math.nan, but does with np.float('nan').

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your question (of why adding `NaN` keys to a Python `dict` create multiple entries), is because **floating-point `NaN` values are unordered**, i.e. a `NaN` value is not equal to, greater than, or less than anything, including itself. This behavior is defined in the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard for floating point arithmetic. The explanation why is that so is given by an IEEE 754 committee member [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/404556).

---

For a longer, Python-specific, answer, let's first have a look at how item insertion and key comparison work in CPython dictionaries.

When you say `d[key] = val`, [`PyDict_SetItem()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L1537) for dictionary `d` is called, which in turn calls (internal) [`insertdict()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L1095), which will either update the existing dictionary item, or insert a new item (maybe resizing the hash table consequentially).

The first step on insert is to lookup the `key` in the hash table of dictionary keys. A general-purpose lookup function that gets called in your case (of non-string keys) is [`lookdict()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L679).

`lookdict` will use `key`'s hash value to locate the `key`, iterating over a list of possible keys with identical hash value, comparing first by address, then by calling `key`s' equivalence operator(s) (see excellent comments in [`Objects/dictobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L132) for more details on hash collision resolution in Python's implementation of [open addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing)).

Since every `float('nan')` **has the same hash** value, yet each one is **a different object** (with a different "identity", i.e. memory address), and they're **not equal by their float-value**:

```
>>> a, b = float('nan'), float('nan')
>>> hash(a), hash(b)
(0, 0)
>>> id(a), id(b)
(94753433907296, 94753433907272)
>>> a == b
False
```

when you say:

```
d = dict()
d[float('nan')] = 1
d[float('nan')] = 2
```

`lookdict` will search for the second `NaN` by looking at its hash (`0`), then trying to resolve hash collision by iterating over keys with the same hash and comparing the keys by identity/address (they are different), then by invoking (the expensive) `PyObject_RichCompareBool`/[`do_richcompare`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L655), which in turn calls [`float_richcompare`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L350) which compares floats just as C does:

```
/* Comparison is pretty much a nightmare.  When comparing float to float,
 * we do it as straightforwardly (and long-windedly) as conceivable, so
 * that, e.g., Python x == y delivers the same result as the platform
 * C x == y when x and/or y is a NaN.
```

which behaves according to IEEE 754 standard (from [GNU C library docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Infinity-and-NaN.html)):

> **20.5.2 Infinity and NaN**
>
> [...]
>
> The basic operations and math functions all accept infinity and NaN and produce sensible output. Infinities propagate through calculations as one would expect: for example, 2 + ∞ = ∞, 4/∞ = 0, atan (∞) = π/2. NaN, on the other hand, infects any calculation that involves it. Unless the calculation would produce the same result no matter what real value replaced NaN, the result is NaN.
>
> In comparison operations, positive infinity is larger than all values except itself and NaN, and negative infinity is smaller than all values except itself and NaN. **NaN is unordered: it is not equal to, greater than, or less than anything, including itself. x == x is false if the value of x is NaN.** You can use this to test whether a value is NaN or not, but the recommended way to test for NaN is with the isnan function (see Floating Point Classes). In addition, <, >, <=, and >= will raise an exception when applied to NaNs.

and which will return `false` for `NaN == NaN`.

That's why Python decides the second `NaN` object is worthy of a new dictionary entry. It may have the same hash, but its address and equivalence test say it is different from all the other `NaN` objects.

However, note that if you always use the same `NaN` object (with the same address) since the address is tested before float equivalence, **you'll get the expected behavior**:

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> d = dict()
>>> d[nan] = 1
>>> d[nan] = 2
>>> d
{nan: 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

For historical reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan), 
`np.float('nan') == np.float('nan')` is False. The rule is just that you can't have two dictionary keys which are equal to each other - so you can have two keys equal to `np.float('nan')`.

Of course, this behavior is counterintuitive and surprising - so you should avoid using `np.float('nan')` as a key.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in a comment to you, `nan` is never "equal" to another `nan`, do your `dict` is writing a new key for it. This is the behavior for `nan` values in most languages, not just python.

I would suggest not using it as a key at all, or at least explain the purpose of it so we can find better ways to achieve that purpose without falling into pitfalls like this.

In your case you could test this bahavior for yourself:

```
a=list(dc.keys())
print(a[0]==a[1]) # will output False
```

The output for the above code (`False`) means that for the system, the are in fact different keys that do not clash