# Python to convert date format from 2/3/13 to 2013-02-03?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to convert my date string to ISO format but it's not working.  Any suggestions on efficiently doing this with `datetime`, `time`, or `pandas`?

```
date = "2/3/13"
import datetime
t = datetime.date(*map(int,date.split("/")))
format = "'%Y-%m-%d'"
t.strftime(format)
# "'0002-03-13'"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With pandas -

```
pd.to_datetime("2/3/13")
Timestamp('2013-02-03 00:00:00')
```

With `pandas`, you can (most of the time) infer the format without having to manually specify it. However, it would seem pointless to import such a heavy module to use it only for a simple datetime conversion.

For that reason, here's an equally simple python way using `strptime` -

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

dt.strptime("2/3/13", '%d/%m/%y')
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 2, 0, 0)
```

Or, even simpler (you don't have to pass a format string), using `dateutil` -

```
from dateutil import parser

parser.parse('2/3/13/').date()
datetime.date(2013, 2, 3)
```

pandas actually uses the `dateutil` library under the hood ([– unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47541415/python-to-convert-date-format-from-2-3-13-to-2013-02-03#comment82040191_47541445)). If your date strings are consistent in structure, I'd recommend using one of these.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to not include the time stamps?  I could just do: `str(x).split(" ")[0]` but I wasn't sure if there was an argument for that

Comment: @BradSolomon Haha I asked a similar question, and the answers to it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842793/datetime-conversion-how-to-extract-the-inferred-format

Comment: @BradSolomon: pandas uses [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html)

Comment: @O.rka `dt.strptime("2/3/13", '%d/%m/%y').date()`

Comment: @O.rka I don't believe you can omit timestamps if you're using pandas.

Comment: These are all great.  There's a few resources online that explain the datetime module but special cases are a little difficult to find. This will be really useful for a quick reference of different methods.

Answer (score 0):

I love me some libraries when it comes to working with date/times. [dateparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dateparser), [parsedatetime](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsedatetime/), and [arrow](http://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) are all really good choices

```
import dateparser as dp

print(dp.parse("2/13/13"))
2013-02-13 00:00:00

print(dp.parse("2/13/13").date())
2013-02-13

print(dp.parse("Yesterday at 2am PST"))
2017-11-27 13:56:59.290385-08:00
```

Cheers