# Inferring date format versus passing a parser

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-dateutil

Pandas internals question: I've been surprised to find a few times that explicitly passing a callable to `date_parser` within `pandas.read_csv` results in *much* slower read time than simply using `infer_datetime_format=True`.

Why is this?  Will timing differences between these two options be date-format-specific, or what other factors will influence their relative timing?

In the below case, `infer_datetime_format=True` takes one-tenth the time of passing a date parser with a specified format.  I would have naively assumed the latter would be faster because it's explicit.

The docs do note,

> [if True,] pandas will attempt to infer the format of the datetime strings in the columns, and if it can be inferred, switch to a faster method of parsing them. In some cases this can increase the parsing speed by 5-10x.

but there's not much detail given and I was unable to work my way fully through the source.

Setup:

```
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(444)
dates = pd.date_range('1980', '2018')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (len(dates), 2)),
                  index=dates).add_prefix('col').reset_index()

# Something reproducible to be read back in
buf = StringIO()
df.to_string(buf=buf, index=False)

def read_test(**kwargs):
    # Not ideal for .seek() to eat up runtime, but alleviate
    # this with more loops than needed in timing below
    buf.seek(0)
    return pd.read_csv(buf, sep='\s+', parse_dates=['index'], **kwargs)

# dateutil.parser.parser called in this case, according to docs
%timeit -r 7 -n 100 read_test()
18.1 ms ± 217 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit -r 7 -n 100 read_test(infer_datetime_format=True)
19.8 ms ± 516 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# Doesn't change with native Python datetime.strptime either
%timeit -r 7 -n 100 read_test(date_parser=lambda dt: pd.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d'))
187 ms ± 4.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I'm interested in knowing a bit about what is going on internally with `infer` to give it this advantage.  My old understanding was that there was already some type of inference going on in the first place because `dateutil.parser.parser` is used if neither is passed.

---

**Update**: did some digging on this but haven't been able to answer the question.

`read_csv()` calls a [helper function](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/io/parsers.py#L3009) which in turn calls [`pd.core.tools.datetimes.to_datetime()`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L106).  That function (accessible as just `pd.to_datetime()`) has both an `infer_datetime_format` and a `format` argument.

However, in this case, the relative timings are very different and don't reflect the above:

```
s = pd.Series(['3/11/2000', '3/12/2000', '3/13/2000']*1000)

%timeit pd.to_datetime(s,infer_datetime_format=True)
19.8 ms ± 1.54 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit pd.to_datetime(s,infer_datetime_format=False)
1.01 s ± 65.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# This was taking the longest with i/o functions,
# now it's behaving "as expected"
%timeit pd.to_datetime(s,format='%m/%d/%Y')
19 ms ± 373 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what happens is that it figures out the format on the first pass and rather than inferring the format for every date, it assumes that each subsequent date is in the same format. Parsing a known format is much faster than figuring out the format then parsing it. I think pandas has fast (i.e cython) paths for some known formats.

Comment: Related... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842793/datetime-conversion-how-to-extract-the-inferred-format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've identified the two important functions: `read_csv` prepares a function to parse the date columns using `_make_date_converter`, and this is always going make a call `to_datetime` (pandas' primary string-to-date conversion tool).

The answers by @WillAyd and @bmbigbang both seem correct to me in that they identify the cause of the slowness as repeated calls of the lambda function.

Since you ask for more details about pandas' source code, I'll try and examine each `read_test` call in more detail below to find out where we end up in `to_datetime` and ultimately why the timings are as you observed for your data.

---

#### `read_test()`

This is very fast because, without any prompts about a possible date format, pandas is going to try and parse the list-like column of strings as though they're approximately in [ISO8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates) (which is a very common case).

Plunging into `to_datetime`, we quickly reach [this code branch](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L361-L369):

```
if result is None and (format is None or infer_datetime_format):
    result = tslib.array_to_datetime(...)
```

From here on, it's [compiled Cython code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx) all the way.

[`array_to_datetime`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/08158c076d89177a962d00e4851649f1ef76d12f/pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx#L2129) iterates through the column of strings to convert each one to datetime format. For each row, we hit [`_string_to_dts`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d9163516dfcf3b16bb1a0a212fd4f802f3839ee4/pandas/_libs/tslibs/np_datetime.pyx#L172-L186) at [this line](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/08158c076d89177a962d00e4851649f1ef76d12f/pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx#L2243); then we go to another short snippet of inlined code ([`_cstring_to_dts`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d9163516dfcf3b16bb1a0a212fd4f802f3839ee4/pandas/_libs/tslibs/np_datetime.pyx#L189-L201)) which means [`parse_iso_8601_datetime`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/648ae4f03622d8eafe1ca3b833bd6a99f56bece4/pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.c#L339-L964) is called to do the actual parsing of the string to a datetime object.

This function is more than capable of parsing dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format and so there is just some housekeeping to finish the job (the C struct filled by `parse_iso_8601_datetime` becomes a proper datetime object, some bounds are checked).

As you can see, `dateutil.parser.parser` is *not* called at all.

---

#### `read_test(infer_datetime_format=True)`

Let's see why this is *almost* as fast as `read_test()`.

Asking pandas to infer the datetime format (and passing no `format` argument) means we land [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L318-L319) in `to_datetime`:

```
if infer_datetime_format and format is None:
    format = _guess_datetime_format_for_array(arg, dayfirst=dayfirst)
```

This calls [`_guess_datetime_format_for_array`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ad043d146b064e50ae732345e1c7b5a5106df3f7/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L32-L36), which takes the first non-null value in the column and gives it to [`_guess_datetime_format`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx#L566-L681). This tries to build a datetime format string to use for future parsing. ([My  answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47045484/3923281) has more detail above the formats it is able recognise.)

Fortunately, the YYYY-MM-DD format is one that can be recognised by this function. Even more fortunately, this particular format has a fast-path through the pandas code!

You can see pandas sets `infer_datetime_format` back to `False` [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L321-L329):

```
if format is not None:
    # There is a special fast-path for iso8601 formatted
    # datetime strings, so in those cases don't use the inferred
    # format because this path makes process slower in this
    # special case
    format_is_iso8601 = _format_is_iso(format)
    if format_is_iso8601:
        require_iso8601 = not infer_datetime_format
        format = None
```

This allows the code to take the [same path as above](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L361-L369) to the `parse_iso_8601_datetime` function.

---

#### `read_test(date_parser=lambda dt: strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d'))`

We've provided a function to parse the date with, so pandas executes [this code block](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/io/parsers.py#L3028-L3033).

However, this raises as exception internally:

```
strptime() argument 1 must be str, not numpy.ndarray
```

This exception is immediately caught, and pandas falls back to using [`try_parse_dates`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1d7b075579ace4d53fe47b13fc50c8e2795998a7/pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx#L397-L436) before calling `to_datetime`.

`try_parse_dates` means that instead of being called on an array, the lambda function is called repeatedly for each value of the array in [this loop](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1d7b075579ace4d53fe47b13fc50c8e2795998a7/pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx#L427-L431):

```
for i from 0 <= i < n:
    if values[i] == '':
        result[i] = np.nan
    else:
        result[i] = parse_date(values[i]) # parse_date is the lambda function
```

Despite being compiled code, we pay the penalty of having function calls to Python code. This makes it very slow in comparison to the other approaches above.

Back in `to_datetime`, we now have an object array filled with `datetime` objects. Again we hit [`array_to_datetime`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/08158c076d89177a962d00e4851649f1ef76d12f/pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx#L2129), but this time [pandas sees a date object](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/b9bd0d7fb2083b29a4943e67d6f646309449bebe/pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx#L553-L562) and uses another function ([`pydate_to_dt64`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/d9163516dfcf3b16bb1a0a212fd4f802f3839ee4/pandas/_libs/tslibs/np_datetime.pyx#L162-L169)) to make it into a datetime64 object.

The cause of the slowdown is really due to the repeated calls to the lambda function.

---

#### About your update and the MM/DD/YYYY format

The Series `s` has date strings in the MM/DD/YYYY format.

This is *not* an ISO8601 format. `pd.to_datetime(s, infer_datetime_format=False)` tries to parse the string using [`parse_iso_8601_datetime`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/648ae4f03622d8eafe1ca3b833bd6a99f56bece4/pandas/_libs/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.c#L339-L964) but this fails with a `ValueError`. The error is handled [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/08158c076d89177a962d00e4851649f1ef76d12f/pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx#L2250-L2265): pandas is going to use [`parse_datetime_string`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1d7b075579ace4d53fe47b13fc50c8e2795998a7/pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx#L68-L106) instead. This means that `dateutil.parser.parse` [is used](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1d7b075579ace4d53fe47b13fc50c8e2795998a7/pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx#L99-L100) to convert the string to datetime. This is why it is slow in this case: repeated use of a Python function in a loop.

There's not much difference between `pd.to_datetime(s, format='%m/%d/%Y')` and `pd.to_datetime(s, infer_datetime_format=True)` in terms of speed. The latter uses  [`_guess_datetime_format_for_array`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/ad043d146b064e50ae732345e1c7b5a5106df3f7/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L32-L36) again to infer the MM/DD/YYYY format. Both then hit `array_strptime` [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py#L346-L347):

```
if format is not None:
    ...
    if result is None:
        try:
            result = array_strptime(arg, format, exact=exact, errors=errors)
```

[`array_strptime`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/1d7b075579ace4d53fe47b13fc50c8e2795998a7/pandas/_libs/tslibs/strptime.pyx#L44) is a fast Cython function for parsing an array of strings to datetime structs given a specific format.

Answer (score 1):

After paying closer attention to
[Pandas original pull request for infer format](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/6021/commits/78bb4671ed5eba36188b48792496d900440a68cd)

I believe the passing of the parser directly is not compatible with pandas'  `._convert_listlike` method. Whereas dateutil's parser is not inherently parallelizable, pandas's convert list like operations can action the parsing in parallel if they can infer the format. The post mentions the format is inferred from the first item, then all others get the same treatment. Being a mathematician, I would probably recommend taking 10 random entries and taking the majority parsed format as the picked one.

**Update** 
As mentioned in the comments, and within the pull request, there are also comparisons between passing the format or the parser: [test gist](https://gist.github.com/danbirken/8533199). It might be worth a feature request to let the parser be a `np.vectorize` object or similar.

Comment: Interesting.  And in [these timings](https://gist.github.com/danbirken/8533199) inferring is either on par or a big leg ahead in terms of speed no matter the format.

Answer (score 1):

`infer_datetime_format` applies the format it deduces to all elements in a single pass (i.e. in a vectorized manner). By contrast, your lambda function gets called for each element, bringing with it a lot more call overhead and decreased performance.

There is a [request from 2012](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2586) for an explicit format keyword argument, which would theoretically give you the functionality you are looking for with the performance you desire. In lieu of that being implemented, your best bet is to go with Wes's suggested approach in the link and simply read the date in as a string, calling `pd.to_datetime` after the fact

Here are sample times from my machine to illustrate:

```
%timeit read_test()
15.4 ms ± 96.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit read_test(infer_datetime_format=True)
17.2 ms ± 1.82 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit read_test(date_parser=lambda dt: pd.datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d'))
147 ms ± 4.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df = read_test(); df['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['index'], '%Y-%m-%d')
15.3 ms ± 239 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```