# How to specify year,month,day in datetime from Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
7542  08/01/2015 00:09:19
7543  08/01/2015 01:01:07
7544  08/01/2015 01:05:42
7545  08/01/2015 01:53:52
7546  08/01/2015 02:28:56
```

I want to convert it to datetime format, but when I use `pd.to_datetime` I get this error:

> ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

I've tried `pd.to_datetime(dataf.stack()).unstack()` and I got a `NaT`.

Comment: try passing `infer_datetime_format=True` to `pd.to_datetime`. It's one of the examples here on the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: I have no problems converting this to datetime using `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: How are you loading your CSV?

Comment: Is there any chance the day/month/year is getting read as part of the index?

Comment: Can you print `df.index` and `df.columns`?

Comment: I printed df.index and the output was 7542, 7543, etc, and df.columns and got this Index(['date'], dtype='object') @HarvIpan

Comment: @JAW I tried that but it didn't work

Comment: @Carolina - Do you try `dataf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataf['date'])` ?

Answer (score 2):

After some playing around, I figured an easy way to do it:

```
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime':['08/01/2015 00:09:19', '08/01/2015 01:01:07', '08/01/2015 01:05:42']})
pd.to_datetime(sample_df.datetime, infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Yeah, it's that simple. I think `to_datetime` needs the data to be in a certain format, and passing the specific column of the dataframe helps it get that format.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `infer_datetime_format=True`, you can also pass a format explicitly:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(sample_df['datetime'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S') 
0   2015-08-01 00:09:19
1   2015-08-01 01:01:07
2   2015-08-01 01:05:42
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I asked a question about this a little while back and there's a great answer from @AlexRiley: [Inferring date format versus passing a parser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48728307/7954504).

Answer (score 0):

Error means your code select `DataFrame`, so `pd.to_datetime` looking for [`year`, `month` and `day` columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37103131/2901002):

```
print (pd.to_datetime(dataf))
```

> ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

---

Solution is select column `date` with parameter `dayfirst=True` if first number is day in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
dataf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataf['date'], dayfirst=True)
print (dataf)
                    date
7542 2015-01-08 00:09:19
7543 2015-01-08 01:01:07
7544 2015-01-08 01:05:42
7545 2015-01-08 01:53:52
7546 2015-01-08 02:28:56

print (dataf.dtypes)
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

**Setup**:

```
d = {'date': {7542: '08/01/2015 00:09:19', 7543: '08/01/2015 01:01:07', 7544: '08/01/2015 01:05:42', 7545: '08/01/2015 01:53:52', 7546: '08/01/2015 02:28:56'}}
dataf = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (dataf)
                     date
7542  08/01/2015 00:09:19
7543  08/01/2015 01:01:07
7544  08/01/2015 01:05:42
7545  08/01/2015 01:53:52
7546  08/01/2015 02:28:56
```