# Pandas to_datetime has inconsistent behavior on non-american dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, string-to-datetime

I am confused by the behavior of pandas `to_datetime` on non-American dates.

In this trivial example, Pandas correctly infers the months on both the 2nd and 3rd row, but fails on the 1st and 4th.

Apparently it is treating the 2nd and 3rd line as `dd/mm/yyyy` dates (because the 13 and 27 clearly can't be months), but treating the remaining dates as being `mm/dd/yyyy`.

My expectation would be that `to_datetime` would infer from the entire series, and then treat every entry the same.

```
import pandas as pd 
results = pd.DataFrame()

european_dates = pd.Series(['05/04/2007',   # <-- April 5th, 2007
                            '13/04/2006',   # <-- April 13th, 2006
                            '27/12/2014',   # <-- December 27th, 2014
                            '02/07/2010'])  # <-- July 2nd, 2010 

# note: the same happens with infer_datetime_format=False
inferred_dates = pd.to_datetime(european_dates,
                                infer_datetime_format=True) 

results['day'] = inferred_dates.dt.day
results['month'] = inferred_dates.dt.month
results['year'] = inferred_dates.dt.year

results
```

[image]

Note: *I'm aware that `to_datetime` has a `dayfirst` argument, and a `format` argument, my question is mostly about why the `infer_datetime_format` fails in such a trivial case.*

Answer (score 1):

Using `dayfirst` in `to_datetime`

```
european_dates = pd.Series(['05/04/2007',   # <-- April 5th, 2007
                            '13/04/2006',   # <-- April 13th, 2006
                            '27/12/2014',   # <-- December 27th, 2014
                            '02/07/2010'])  # <-- July 2nd, 2010 
inferred_dates = pd.to_datetime(european_dates,dayfirst =True) 
results = pd.DataFrame()
results['day'] = inferred_dates.dt.day
results['month'] = inferred_dates.dt.month
results['year'] = inferred_dates.dt.year
results
Out[109]: 
   day  month  year
0    5      4  2007
1   13      4  2006
2   27     12  2014
3    2      7  2010
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as I mentioned in the original question, I'm aware of both `dayfirst` and `format`. The question is about why the behavior of the `infer_datetime_format` is inconsistent, not about finding a workaround.

Comment: @sapo_cosmico cause dayfirst default is false when the first can be month it will convert to m rather than d

Comment: True, do you know if there is any way for it to infer consistently? (i.e. _"If not all rows can have month first, it can never be month first"_)

Comment: @sapo_cosmico rafer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842793/datetime-conversion-how-to-extract-the-inferred-format