# How to retrieve strptime model with string and datetime object available?

Tags: python, datetime, parsing, strptime

Suppose I have a large set of strings I want to parse to a set of datetime objects. I could use the `dateutils.parser` and iterate through the set but it is more computer intensive and takes a longer time than parsing one, retrieving the strptime format applied and just do `datetime.strptime(string, model)`.

I wanted to create a function, a bit like the following:

```
def retrieve_format(datetime_object, string):
    #do some things
    return model
```

with the `model` being a string.

I have found nothing that explains the inner workings of the dateutils parser, and I believe the developers have the ability to add such a feature.

Any idea on how to do it ? **It would save time and computing power.**

**Example**

Suppose I have a set of string that are formatted the same way as this one:

```
myStr = '27/03/2020 - 16:20'
```

I could do

```
myDate = dateutils.parser.parse(myStr)
```

and get 'myDate' as being

```
datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 27, 16, 20)
```

but now I could use my function as such

```
>>> model = retrieve_format(myDate, myStr)
>>> print(model)
%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M
```

I could then do

```
datetime_set = {}
for formatted_string in set:
    raw = datetime.datetime.strptime(formatted_string, model)
    datetime_set.add(raw)
```

to treat all the other elements very efficiently.

Comment: Similar (but  pandas-heavy) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842793/datetime-conversion-how-to-extract-the-inferred-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so thanks to snakecharmerb's comment on my question, I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47083238/10860121) which uses the [dateinfer](https://github.com/wdm0006/dateinfer) library. Here, just the string is needed. Installation with pip is possible

```
pip install pydateinfer
```

A working example would be the following

```
import dateinfer
dateinfer.infer(['27/03/2020 - 16:20', '28/03/2020 - 14:56' ])
```

and the output is

```
'%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M'
```

The input is always a list, even if it contains only one element.
**Depending on the ambiguity of the string, the list should have more or less elements.** That is because for example in '04/04/2020', we have no means of distinguishing the day or the month.