# Finding correct strftime format dynamically?

Tags: python, datetime, strptime, strftime

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date    
        
DateTime = "2021-05-25T13:52:50.980437-04:00"
String_Format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

**Error Message:**

> time data '2021-05-25T13:52:50.980437-04:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

How can I reliably figure out the datetime formats for any datetime format that comes into my data sets?

Comment: Automatically?  You can't.  There are too many variations.  Consider 12/12/12.  Which one is the month, which is the day, which is the year?

Comment: Besides, you're looking for a parsing directive for `strptime`; strftime is for conversion of datetime object to string. And for standardized formats as the one you show, there's [datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat).

Comment: related: [Datetime conversion - How to extract the inferred format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46842793/10197418)

Answer (score 1):

try checking several known formats in a loop

```
from datetime import datetime

def parse(v):
  for fmt in ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'):
    try:
      return datetime.strptime(v, fmt)
    except ValueError as e:
      continue
    raise e

parse('2021-05-25T13:52:50.980437-04:00')
```

also, in your particular example, you are missing `%f`