# Java (Math.max) var0 != var0

Tags: java, max, equals, primitive

Can anyone please explain to me what is the point of `var0 != var0` in Math.max(a, b) method?

```
public static float max(float var0, float var1) {
  if (var0 != var0) {
    return var0;
  } else if (var0 == 0.0F && var1 == 0.0F && (long)Float.floatToRawIntBits(var0) == negativeZeroFloatBits) {
    return var1;
  } else {
    return var0 >= var1 ? var0 : var1;
  }
}
```

Comment: NaN perhaps? Not sure.

Comment: Also what's the idea behind converting `Float.floatToRawIntBits()` to long?  You don't gain anything by doing that.

Comment: if (a != a)
            return a;   // a is NaN

Comment: Does that matter though?  The last line should return var0 anyway if var0 is NAN.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan

Comment: Yes, NaN is it!

Comment: I think it's a bad test though, they should be testing var1 for NAN, because that won't be returned by the last line if either input is NAN.

Comment: @markspace The last condition returns `var1` if it's `NaN`, not `var0` since `var0 >= Float.NaN == false`.

Comment: Oh, ternary is true first, then false.  Sorry got those mixed up. @Kayaman  Now I'm just confused about the middle part.  Testing for +0 vs -0?

Comment: @markspace yes, negative 0 is smaller than positive 0 in this case. Not the most straightforward method to read, considering all the intricacies involved.

Comment: As for why the check is done as `var0 != var0` instead of `Float.isNaN(var0)`, that's an optimization.