# What allows NaN to work with the Python list inclusion operator?

Tags: python, nan, equality

Pretty much anyone who works with IEEE floating-point values has run into NaN, or "not a number", at some point. Famously, [NaN is not equal to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124383/what-is-the-intuitive-reason-that-nan-nan).

```
>>> x = float('nan')
>>> x == x
False
```

Now, I had come to terms with this, but there's a strange behavior I'm struggling to wrap my head around. Namely,

```
>>> x in [x]
True
```

I had always assumed that `list.__contains__` was written something like

```
def __contains__(self, element):
    for x in self:
        if element == x:
            return True
    return False
```

i.e., it used `__eq__` on the relevant data type internally. And indeed it does. If I define a custom class with an `__eq__` method of my own design, then I can verify that Python does in fact call `__eq__` when doing the inclusion check. But then how can there exist a value `x` (NaN in our case) such that `x == x` is false but `x in [x]` is true?

We can observe the same behavior with a custom `__eq__` as well.

```
class Example:

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False

x = Example()
print(x == x)   # False
print(x in [x]) # True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) it first uses the `is` operator to check for equality, and since `x is x` is `True`, `x in [x]` is also `True`:

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

Note that identity (`is`) is different from equality (`==`). Also note that not all NaN values are represented by the same object, so if you try your test with two different NaN objects:

```
>>> float('nan') in [float('nan')]
False
```

you'll see different results.