# Why does this list vs array evaluation returns false when nan values are present?

Tags: python, numpy

Consider this simple evaluation:

```
import numpy as np

aa = np.array([[np.nan, np.nan], [1.64, 0.0784]]) 
bb = [[np.nan, np.nan], [1.64, 0.0784]]

np.all(aa == bb)
```

This returns `False`, even though the `aa` array is equal to the `bb` list. If I try this for each element in `aa, bb` I get:

```
np.all(aa[0] == bb[0])
False
np.all(aa[1] == bb[1])
True
```

Which means the `nan` values are the issue here. Why is this happening?

Comment: The why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, `nan` compared to anything (using built-in operands) returns `False`.  In particular, `np.nan == np.nan` returns `False`.

Note, however, that `!=` is defined as the negation of `==`, so we get:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
>>> np.nan != np.nan
True
```

You can check directly using

```
>>> np.isnan(np.nan)
True
```