# delete all nan values from list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

if any elements are there along with nan then i want to keep element and want to delete nan only like

**example 1 ->**

```
index      values
0     [nan,'a',nan,nan]
```

**output** should be like

```
index   values

0         [a]
```

**example 2->**

```
index      values
0     [nan,'a',b,c]

1     [nan,nan,nan]
```

**output** should be like

```
index   values

0      [a,b,c]

1        []
```

Answer (score 8):

This is one approach using `df.apply`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, "a", np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan], ["a", "b"]]})
df["a"] = df["a"].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if str(i) != "nan"])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
        a
0     [a]
1      []
2  [a, b]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the fact that `np.nan == np.nan` evaluates to `False`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, [np.nan, 'a', 'b', 'c']],
                   [1, [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]],
                   [2, [np.nan, 'a', np.nan, np.nan]]],
                  columns=['index', 'values'])

df['values'] = df['values'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i == i])

print(df)

   index     values
0      0  [a, b, c]
1      1         []
2      2        [a]
```

`lambda` is just an anonymous function. You could also use a named function:

```
def remove_nan(x):
    return [i for i in x if i == i]

df['values'] = df['values'].apply(remove_nan)
```

Related: [Why is NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Can you please tell me how lambda function is working here ?
Difficult to understand i==i

Comment: @ShubhamThagunna, `lambda` is an anonymous function. It defines logic which is applied to each item in a sequence. Here the items are elements of the series `df['values']`. See update for the equivalent with a named function.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['values'].apply(lambda v: pd.Series(v).dropna().values )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.Series.map` on `df.values`

```
import pandas as pd
my_filter = lambda x: not pd.isna(x)
df['new_values'] = df['values'].map(lambda x: list(filter(my_filter, x)))
```