# Can this return true function canbetrue(x) { return x != x; }

Tags: javascript

A friend asked me this question he got during a job interview

```
function canbetrue(x) {
return x != x;
}
```

Which value of `param` will make the above function return **true** ?

```
console.log(canbetrue(param));
```

Comment: If x == false then the function return true

Comment: @Osama no it does not

Comment: @Osama you're wrong on that one, look where the ! is. If it was to return true it would be x = !x; They would have to parse NaN to return true.

Comment: Take a look at [Why is NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan)

Comment: it returns false ? if x != x is always false

Comment: Sory I get it now NAN is the right value

Comment: @newbie : try console.log(canbetrue(NaN)) . It will return true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NaN is what you are looking for...

```js
function canbetrue(x) {
return x != x;
}
console.log(canbetrue(NaN));
```