# fill new column of pandas DataFrame based on if-else of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a situation where I want to create a new column in a Pandas DataFrame and populate it according to conditions involving 2 other columns. In this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['value1','value2'],['value',np.NaN],[np.NaN,np.NaN]]), columns=['col1','col2'])
```

I would like to create a new column, 'new col', which consists of 1) the value in 'col2' if it is not NaN else, 2) the value in 'col1' if it is not NaN else, 3) NaN

I am trying this function with .apply() but it is not returning the desired result

```
def singleval(row):
    if row['col2'] != np.NaN:
        val = row['col2']
    elif row['col1'] != np.NaN:
        val = row['col1']
    else:
        val = np.NaN
    return val

df['new col'] = df.apply(singleval,axis=1)
```

i want the values in 'new col' to be `['value2', 'value', 'nan']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Method 1 `fillna`

In this case, we can simply use `fillna` on `col2` with values from `col1`:

```
df['new col'] = df['col2'].fillna(df['col1'])
```

---

```
     col1    col2 new col
0  value1  value2  value2
1   value     NaN   value
2     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

---

## Method 2 `np.select`

If you have multiple conditions, use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) which you pass a list of conditions and based on those conditions you pass it choices:

```
conditions = [
    df['col2'].notnull(),
    df['col1'].notnull(),
]

choices=[df['col2'], df['col1']]

df['new col'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.NaN)
```

---

```
     col1    col2 new col
0  value1  value2  value2
1   value     NaN   value
2     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

**Note**

Your dataframe wasn't correct with the `NaN`, use this one instead to test:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['value1', 'value', np.NaN],
                   'col2':['value2', np.NaN, np.NaN]})
```

**Edit: why was the function not working?**

`np.NaN == np.NaN` will return `False`
while `np.NaN is np.NaN` will return `True`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan) for the explanation of this.

So to fix your function you have to use `is not`:

```
def singleval(row):
    if row['col2'] is not np.NaN:
        val = row['col2']
    elif row['col1'] is not np.NaN:
        val = row['col1']
    else:
        val = np.NaN
    return val

df['new col'] = df.apply(singleval, axis=1)
```

---

```
     col1    col2 new col
0  value1  value2  value2
1   value     NaN   value
2     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: struggling to see why your df is different from my df...nevermind: looks like it has to do with np.array()

Comment: Not sure either, would be a good question on SO as well :). @laszlopanaflex

Comment: thank you the 2 solutions. is it possible to explain why my original approach didn't work? im not able to see where the if-elif-else approach breaks down...

Comment: Added explanation about your approach @laszlopanaflex, good question btw!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['col3'] = df[['col1','col2']].stack().groupby(level=0).last()
```

output:

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   value1  value2  value2
1   value   nan     value
2   nan     nan     nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `df.ffill` on `axis=1`

```
df['new_col'] = df.ffill(1).col2

Out[1318]:
     col1    col2 new_col
0  value1  value2  value2
1   value     NaN   value
2     NaN     NaN     NaN
```