# accessing pandas columns with loc and square brackets comparison element wise

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, boolean, nan

In a particular dataframe I have a column called "Wind" giving me the wind energy production per year in Germany.
At the beginning of the sequence the production is so small that is written NaN in the DF, no data available. Only from 2010 on I have data for wind.

DATA link for copy and paste:
            API_link_to_data='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenfly/opsd/master/opsd_germany_daily.csv'

```
energyDF = pd.read_csv(API_link_to_data)
```

now the the following code compares two columns element wise:

```
energyDF.loc[:,'Wind'] == energyDF['Wind']
```

I expected the result to be [True, True, True,....,True]

but this is not the case.
For the NaN values the result is False.

Well the result is false for all the NaN values, even if element wise they are the same:

```
print(wind_col1[0])
print(wind_col2[0])
print(wind_col1[0] == wind_col2[0])
print(wind_col1[0] == np.nan)
print(wind_col2[0] == np.nan)
```

Result:
nan
nan
False
False
False

Expected:
nan
nan
True
True
True

and after doing to the whole frame:

```
energyDF=energyDF.fillna(0)
```

then

```
energyDF.loc[:,'Wind'] == energyDF['Wind']
```

is a list full of Trues.

Could someone explain that?

Thanks

Comment: This is expected. `NaN`s are not equal to anything. Imo the best way would be to fillna with a value not present in the dataframe and then check equality

Comment: wooooohhh Didn't know it nan is not equal to anything.

Comment: @AsishM. propose a solution and I will vote for it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NaN`s are not equal to themselves. See: [Why is NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan)

As for checking equality of `energyDF.loc[:,'Wind'] == energyDF['Wind']`

you could `fillna` both sides with a value (preferably one that doesn't occur in the series) and then check that both are indeed identical

as an example:

```
>>> df
    ID Col1
0  1.0   AD
1  NaN   BC
2  3.0   CE
>>> (df.loc[:, 'ID'] == df['ID']).all()
False
>>> (df.loc[:, 'ID'].fillna("Non-existent") == df['ID'].fillna("Non-existent")).all()
True
```