# missing value conditions Pandas in a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, missing-data

I would like a function where if the area column has missing values (like NULL in SQL) the result is 'A' in the target 'wanted' variable.

I'm confused about use of None, isnull(), np.nan concepts in Python

```
raw_data = {'area': ['S','W',np.nan,np.nan], 'wanted': [np.nan,np.nan,'A','A']}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['area','wanted'])
df


def my_func(x):
    if (x) is None:
        return 'A'
    else:
        return np.nan


df['wanted2'] = df['area'].apply(my_func)

df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.nan` is not equal to `None`  , [infact `NaN` isnot equal to `NaN` as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan) (check `np.nan == None`) , hence you can utilize `pd.isna()` in your if condition:

```
def my_func(x):
    if pd.isna(x):
        return 'A'
    else:
        return np.nan


df['wanted2'] = df['area'].apply(my_func)
```

but you can vectorize this using `np.where` and `series.isna()` instead of using `apply`

```
df['wanted2'] = np.where(df['area'].isna(),'A',np.nan)
```

Comment: thanks and just to know, the opposite of "pd.isna(x)", not having NULL, how is it?

Comment: @progster `pd.notna(x)` , similarly for a series , we have `series.notna()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fill.na](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
df['wanted2'] = df.area.fillna('A')
```

In your code return `np.nan` if the value exists in `area` and 'A' otherwise.

Comment: thanks but in order to understand I would like to do it wih my function, because this is only an example, in real life the conditions are more complex

Comment: Given your input, was is your expect output?

Comment: my target was having something like the 'wanted' variable