# Get index of tuple with "NaN" from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, nan

I have a list of tuples with one element as `NaN`:

```
l = [('a', 7.0), ('b', float('nan'))]
```

And I want to find the index of tuple `('b', float('nan'))` in the above list.

`l.index(('b', float('nan'))` is unable to find the element in the list even though its index is 1. It is raising `ValueError` exception as:

```
>>> l.index(('b', float('nan'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: ('b', nan) is not in list
```

Most likely this is due to the fact that each `float('nan')` is an independent NaN object, meaning that the two tuples are different objects as well.

How do I solve this problem in general?

Comment: Because `float('nan') == float('nan')` returns `False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float('nan') == float('nan')` returns `False` because it is designed to not to match with itself. That's why `list.index()` function is unable to find a match for `NaN` value and is raising `ValueError` exception.

Please read [*Why is NaN not equal to NaN?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23666623/2063361) to know more about this behaviour.

Below is a custom function `check_nan_match()` to check whether passed objects are having same value or not. This function will be able to match for `NaN` objects too based on the above property i.e. *`NaN`s return `False` when matched with itself*.

```
# Function too check passed values are match, including `NaN`
def check_nan_match(a, b):
    return (b != b and a != a) or a == b
          # ^    ^ `NaN` property to return False when matched with itself
```

To get the index of `tuple` in the `list` containing `NaN`, here I am creating another custom function as `get_nan_index`. This function accepts `my_list` and `my_tuple` as param, iterates over the `my_list` to get the index of `my_tuple`. To check for the equality, I am using previously created `check_nan_match` function which is capable to match `NaN` values too.

```
# Get index from list of tuple , when tuple is passed
def get_nan_index(my_list, my_tuple):
    for i, t in enumerate(my_list):
        if all(check_nan_match(x, y) for x, y in zip(t, my_tuple)):
            return i
    else:
        raise ValueError  # Raise `ValueError` exception in case of no match.
                          # Similar to `list.index(...)` function
```

Sample run:

```
# check for tuple with `NaN` 
>>> get_nan_index([('a', 7.0), ('b', float('nan'))], ('b', float('nan')))
1

# check for tuple without `NaN`
>>> get_nan_index([('a', 1), ('b', 2)], ('b', 2))
1

# `ValueError` exception if no match
>>> get_nan_index([('a', 7.0), ('b', 3)], ('b', float('nan')))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in get_nan_index
ValueError
```

Comment: If you just want the first index with short-circuiting, `next(i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(l) if x == 'b' and isnan(y))` will do it (also make sure to test both values).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Handling different edge cases in generator with `next()` won't be clean. Having it in form of custom functions I created above would be much cleaner approach in my opinion