# How can I drop non string type 'nan' from list

Tags: python, list, numpy, nan

I have the data coming from the field. It is in list format. The elements are float. Some unexpected character like `nan` is seen in the list. But it is not in string format. I tried existing solutions but failed to remove them.

My code:

```
lst = [1.2,2.3,nan]

newlst = [x for x in lst if str(x) != 'nan']
```

Present output:

```
NameError: name 'nan' is not defined
```

Expected output:

```
newlst = [1.2,2.3]
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a [**`math.isnan()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isnan) which could be used to identify the `NaN`s. You can use this inside *list comprehension* to achieve this as:

```
>>> import math
>>> lst = [1.2,2.3,float('nan')]

>>> [i  for i in lst if not math.isnan(i)]
[1.2, 2.3]
```

Additionally, one of the property of `'NaN'` numbers is that they return `False` when compared with itself. You can also utilise this property to identify them and filter them out as:

```
>>> [i  for i in lst if i==i]
[1.2, 2.3]
```

Refer [*Why is NaN not equal to NaN?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10034149/2063361) for more details.