# Why if x!=np.nan is not working in the lambda method?

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda

Given that i have a below datadrame:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({"Cabin" : ["Hello","Morning",np.NAN,"BBC"]})
```

I wish to apply the following process on the Cabin column:

```
dt["Cabin"].map(lambda x: x[0] if x!=np.nan else np.nan )
```

But, i am facing with the below error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I can understand the `if x!=np.nan` is not working, but i don't know how to fix it ?

The expected output is as following

```
expected_output = pd.DataFrame({"Cabin" : ["H","M",np.NAN,"B"]})
```

Comment: What's the expected outcome?

Comment: I think the root problem here is that you're expecting `np.NAN != np.NAN` to be `False` so that `x[0]` won't be evaluated when `x` is nan.

Comment: The lambda will always return `np.nan` since `np.nan != np.nan`.

Comment: *NOTHING* is equal to `nan` - not even `nan`.  Numpy has a `np.isnan()` function for performing this test.

Comment: Of course numpy.NAN is not subscriptable

Comment: Its the Nan inequality problem addressed in several areas like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html): instead of explicitly checking for nan yourself, just pass `na_action='ignore'`.

Comment: @jasonharper i need to check if it is not `nan`. I tried the `lambda x: x[0] if !np.isnan(x) else np.nan` but it has syntax error !!!

Comment: What other values can be in this column? I see string and Nan, can there be other things like non-Nan float?

Comment: @Jeff while the linked dupes answer your actual question, you're over complicating this based on your example data - just use `df['Cabin'].str[0]`

Comment: Try `if not np.isnan(x)`