# Replacing blank rows in a column with the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a date column but some values are blank or NaN, I am trying to replace all these values with a date from another column.  I am trying the solution below but its not working, can someone please help

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace(np.nan, df['Date2'])
```

Comment: `df['Date'].fillna(df['Date2'])`

Comment: Note that the `replace` method does not find any `np.nan`, probably because `np.nan == np.nan` evals to `False`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10034186/18482459

Comment: thanks @mozway your solution worked, unfortunatley you posted the answer in a comment so I cant award you the credit

Comment: @Samir112 no need to, it's a well known answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

> some values are blank or NaN

You can first replace empty strings with `NaN` with [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) then use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html).

Try this :

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].replace("", np.NaN).fillna(df['Date2'])
```