# How to compare NaN and NaN is equal in unit test

Tags: flutter, dart, nan

I have a unit test where my result and my expected result have value NaN, but when I do

```
expect(result, expected);
```

this returns

```
Expected: <NaN>
  Actual: <NaN>
```

I understand this happens for this reason [Why is NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan)

But is there any way to override the equal comparison in order for these two values to be equal? Or maybe some other solution?

I know that I can do `result.isNaN` but I use a `Map` for testing that looks like this

```
{
    'expect': {
        2: 2.0,
        '2.': 2.0,
        '-2.5': -2.5,
        '.5': 0.5,
        '2020-01-06T14:31:00.135Z': double.nan,
        'foo': double.nan,
    }
}
```

where I iterate through each key and compare the value (expected) with my result, so the `result`, and `expected` values above are dynamic that's why I would like to avoid doing special if condition just for checking NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace the values in the map by [matcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-matcher_matcher/package-matcher_matcher-library.html):

```
2: equals(2),
'foo': isNaN
```

Then update your logic (looks like it will work as is).