# Mapping strip() to strings in pandas dataframe does not change NaN entries but still claims that they are different?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda, mapping

I have a dataframe where I have very different kinds of entries (text, integers, floats, times, etc.) and I am trying to delete leading and trailing whitespaces from text entries so that my other code would work as expected. However, my code does not seem to work.

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(([np.nan, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])), columns=["one", "two", "three"])
print(df1)
print("")
df2 = df1.map(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
print(df2)
print("")
print(df1==df2)
print("")
cell1 = df1.at[0, "one"]
cell2 = df2.at[0, "one"]
print(cell1, type(cell1))
print(cell2, type(cell2))
print(cell1==cell2)
```

When I run this code, the output is:

```
   one  two  three
0  NaN  2.0    3.0
1  4.0  5.0    6.0

   one  two  three
0  NaN  2.0    3.0
1  4.0  5.0    6.0

     one   two  three
0  False  True   True
1   True  True   True

nan <class 'numpy.float64'>
nan <class 'numpy.float64'>
False
```

As you can see, `df1` and `df2` have exactly the same entires (NaN) but the code block `print(cell1==cell2)` claims that these cells are different.

What is going on in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how floats work, you can't compare directly `NaN`s ([Why is NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan))

Use [`Dataframe.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html#pandas-dataframe-equals) to compare the dataframes:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(([np.nan, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])), columns=["one", "two", "three"]
)

df2 = df1.map(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)

print(df1.equals(df2))
```

Prints:

```
True
```